# Error on react-router-dom. Switch command

Tags: javascript, routes, switch-statement

I am trying to make a react navigation with react-router-dom but I have an compiling error that I can't solve

This is what I tried.

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Inicio from './Components/Inicio';
import Pedido from './Components/Pedido';
import Reservar from './Components/Reservar';
import IniciarSesion from './Components/IniciarSesion';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Inicio} exact>
          <Inicio/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/pedido" component={Pedido} exact>
          <Pedido/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/reservar" component={Reservar} exact>
          <Reservar/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/iniciarsesion" component={IniciarSesion} exact>
          <IniciarSesion/>
        </Route>    
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the error.

```
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' (imported as 'Switch').
ERROR in ./src/App.js 19:35-41
export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, 
BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_enhanceManualRouteObjects, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Could somebody give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

What's your version of `react-router-dom` ?

In the version `6.x.x` `<Switch>` was replaced by `<Routes>`.

If your library is indeed in the version `6.x.x` follow this official documentation to upgrade it: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

You could also look at [data routers](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) that brings a lots of cool features like preventing the user to leave the page when the page contain unsaved changes